# The jQuery Validation `valid()` method returns 0 when required is not true

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm using the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) and I've got a textbox with the class `digits` to force it to be digits only, but not required.  When I call validate on the form it works fine, but if I call `valid()` on the textbox when it's empty, it returns 0, despite no error message showing and required not being set.

Does anyone know why it would be returning this for a seemingly valid input value?

Here is the code:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="kiloMetresTravelled" id="kiloMetresTravelled" class="digits"/>
```

and the script

```
<script type="text/javascript'>
 var isvalid = jQuery('#kiloMetresTravelled').valid(); 
 //isvalid == 0 when kiloMetresTravelled is blank
</script>
```

Comment: Whoops, read the question wrong. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this, from the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/digits):

> Makes "field" required and digits
>   only.

You could do something like this:

```
var isValid = jQuery('#kiloMetresTravelled').valid() || jQuery('#kiloMetresTravelled').val() == "";
```

Comment: Doesn't it only say 'makes the element require digits only'.  They added a 'required' rule as well

Comment: The example adds the required rule into the mix: this answer is misleading. What actually happens is that since there is no required rule on the field, the internal 'check' method returns undefined for the field in question. Why this is so is a mystery to me. Note that the code above works but (a) the reason is wrong, and (b) it will only work for a single element under test.

Answer (score 2):

I think this works:

```
var e="#whatever";
var isValid = $(e).valid() || $(e).val()== "" && !$(e).hasClass('required');
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug on the library when rule methods check for optional fields with "this.optional(element)". When the field is empty this.optional returns "dependency-mismatch" and the validation method returns "undefined" marking the field as invalid.

Full explanation here:

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/481