# jquery validation: submit button enabled only if all watched elements validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Watching multiple elements in a form, I would like to **enable** the submit button only when all elements successfully validate. Here's what I have attempted:-

```
$('#beta_signup_form').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true 
        }
    },
    focusCleanup: true,
    onkeyup: false,
    errorElement: "span",
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        if ($('#beta_signup_form').valid()) {
            console.log("now we enable the submit button!");
        }   
    }

});
```

**UPDATES**

I was expecting the `submitHandler` to be triggered and the if `if ($('#beta_signup_form').valid())` condition to check that all our fields are valid, before we enable the submit button so that the user can click on it to make an ajax call to submit the form.

But somehow, nothing gets triggered when all fields are valid.

I figured out what I am getting wrong and that is the `submitHandler` attribute has nothing to do with detecting the "all fields validated" event.  The `submitHandler` attribute only gets fired if I click on my form button, which is not what I need.

So my question is - which is the event I need to bind to? Is there an attribute that can be used for setting up a trigger when **all fields in the form** validate?

Here's the form html code:-

```
    <form id="beta_signup_form" postUrl="{% url 'signups_beta_users' %}" method="post" csrf_token="{{ csrf_token }}">{% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" />
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="request-trial" href="#request-for-free-trial">Notify Me</button>
        <div class="loading"></div>
    </form>
```

Comment: This link shoud help you out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882406/jquery-disable-button-not-submit-until-field-validates-validation-plugin

Comment: Yes. I read through this but it does not work for multiple fields. The `success` event gets triggered the moment 1 field gets validated while the rest of the fields are still empty, which is not good enough for my purpose. I need to trigger the "enable button" event **only** when ALL fields in the form validate.

Comment: You do not need to conditionally check `$('#beta_signup_form').valid()` within the `submitHandler`.  By definition, the form is already valid when the code within `submitHandler` function is fired.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/tCpXT/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#beta_signup_form").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert('submitted');
        }
    });
});​
```

I am posting my answer in response to [the previously accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13764485/594235) to demonstrate that you do not need any special function to do what the OP is asking.  The `.validate()` plugin already behaves like this by default.

This is the jsFiddle from the accepted answer:  http://jsfiddle.net/99mbLp1b/

Within that answer, the only difference is this bit of conditional code used within the `submitHandler`.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {

    if ($("#beta_signup_form").valid()) {
        alert('now we enable the submit button!');
    }  

}
```

[As per the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), The `submitHandler` is the *"Callback for handling the actual submit **when the form is valid**."*

So if the `submitHandler` is only called when the form is valid, then this whole conditional check is completely superfluous and unnecessary...

```
if ($("#beta_signup_form").valid()) { ... };
```

It's always going to be `true`, since you'd never even get into the `submitHandler` function if the form wasn't already valid.

See demo for proof:  http://jsfiddle.net/uehu47w1/

As you can see, it operates identically as [the jsFiddle within the other answer](http://jsfiddle.net/99mbLp1b/).

Answer (score 2):

This code works perfectly for me (see here : http://jsfiddle.net/tCpXT/) :

```
            <form id="beta_signup_form" postUrl="" method="post">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" />
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="request-trial" href="#request-for-free-trial">Notify Me</button>
                <div class="loading"></div>
            </form>​
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#beta_signup_form").validate({
                rules: {
                    name: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 4
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true 
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    if ($("#beta_signup_form").valid()) {
                        alert('now we enable the submit button!');
                    }   
                }
                });

            });
            </script>
```

Comment: Yes. This works perfectly. My bad. I have a conflicting event (legacy code) bounded to my button and that was the reason causing my grieve.

Comment: [Exactly how is this behavior any different than what the `.validate()` plugin does by default?](http://jsfiddle.net/tCpXT/1/)  http://jsfiddle.net/tCpXT/1/

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you also have to test for 0 (see here : [The jQuery Validation `valid()` method returns 0 when required is not true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482224/the-jquery-validation-valid-method-returns-0-when-required-is-not-true))

So it would be :

```
 if (($('#beta_signup_form').valid())||($('#beta_signup_form').valid()=="")) {
        console.log("now we enable the submit button!");
    }
```